# Extra threads while calling [NSScreen mainScreen]

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is what I observed while debugging my application. My application is essentially a single threaded application.

Application initially has only one thread.

Thread 1: Queue: com.apple.main-thread.

In my application, when the following code is hit

```
 NSScreen * mainscreen = [NSScreen mainScreen];
```

then following threads are created.

1. Thread 3: Queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
2. Thread 5
3. Thread 6
4. Thread 7

Call stack of Thread 3 is 
kevent64
_dispatch_mgr_thread

Call stack of Thread 5, 6 and 7 is
__workq_kernreturn
start_wqthread

Why thread 3, 5, 6 and 7 appears suddenly on [NSScreen mainScreen]?

After the application is loaded, when I break it, it shows a Thread 16 CVDisplayLink. What is CVDisplayLink?

I am using Mac OS X Mavericks Preview and Xcode 5 for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [Mac Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVDisplayLinkRef/Reference/reference.html):

> A Core Video display link provides a separate high-priority thread to
>   notify your application when a given display will need each frame. You
>   can use a display link to easily synchronize with the refresh rate of
>   a display. The display link API uses the Core Foundation class system
>   internally to provide reference counting behavior and other useful
>   properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is com.apple.libdispatch-manager? What is the meaning of Queue after the thread name as shown in the callstack?

Comment: Also, I am not using CVDisplayLink. Why is it there?

Comment: @dbasic Sorry I don't know what every one of those system threads are to be honest; I know they provide the infrastructure for notifications etc.  I'm not even sure they are properly documented, however `CVDisplayLink` is at least mentioned in the docs.  They will generally always exist in an app, whether they are used or not.

Comment: @dbasic: `com.apple.libdispatch-manager` is part of the Grand Central Dispatch implementation. The other threads may be GCD worker threads. As long as they're just sitting around waiting for something to do, and not actually doing anything, they're harmless.